# Migration column not created on heroku db, visible on local - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

this is the migration file

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :comments do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.string :email
          t.text :body
          t.boolean :spam, default: false
          t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
          t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end
```

the user_id column is not created on heroku for some reason.

actual table on heroku

```
Comment(id: integer, name: string, email: string, body: text, post_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I have tried `heroku restart` maybe it updates schema or something but nothing.

on my local env i can see and can work with user_id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose instead of creating a new migration you modified an existing one.

What you need to do is `rollback` the migration on *Heroku* and than `migrate` it again.

Keep in mind that you will have to create two commits to your repo, one withwout the modifications and on with. This is due to the fact that when rolling back the migration the added column should be missing or it will attempt to delete a column that does not exists.

So the procedure is the following:

1. Remove the modifications from the migration. Commit the changes.
2. `heroku run rake db:rollback STEP=1` or however many steps you need.
3. Add the modifications again. Commit the changes.
4. `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - I'm supposing that is your last migration -

`heroku run rake db:rollback` to rollback the last migration

`heroku run rake db:migrate` to run that migration again